# How do I force Firefox Selenium Webdriver(Python) to accept any SSL certificates

Tags: selenium, firefox, ssl, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to fix testing for an internal app and I don't care about security at the moment (I just want it to work).

It's giving me SSL warnings which breaks the testing. Specifically Your connection is not secure/ SEC_ERROR_UNKOWN_ISSUER.

I've tried both setting `capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True` and

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
```

and neither works. The capabilities listed by the driver after constructing it has acceptSslCerts as false.

Note I'm using Python and Firefox 47.

Also I switched to using the new marionette Firefox Webdriver because the regular one was crashing on startup.

Comment: Also give the Chromedriver a try. As it works a bit more stable then Firefox together with Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the Firefox Version 47 (see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110).

So you are good to go to **wait** for a fix of Firefox/Selenium or you **downgrade** to **Firefox 46**.

Comment: The incompatible messages are always a bit different and strange. So give it a try if you really need it.

Comment: the issue was that trusting ssl untrusted certs isn't available w/ marionette yet(https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196) switched back to the classic driver and firefox 45

Comment: Good to know. I switched to Chrome meanwhile as it is not as buggy as Firefox. Sadly, as huge Firefox fan. =/

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox Self-signed certificate bug has now been fixed: [accept ssl cert with marionette firefox webdrive python splinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868425/accept-ssl-cert-with-marionette-firefox-webdrive-python-splinter/41711649#41711649)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
ff_binary = FirefoxBinary("path to the Nightly binary")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=caps)
driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com")
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm sticking with the old driver for now

Comment: Before it worked on the latest Firefox + driver + selenium, the last configuration with which my tests worked was:
Firefox v46
geckodriver v0.8.0
selenium v2.53.6

I hope it can help you