# How to add new trusted certificate for firefox profile

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, firefox-marionette

Upgrading to Firefox 47 leaves one with the only option to use the `marionette` web driver. It seems to not support untrusted certificates though:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868534/520567

I'm struggling to find a way to import certificate when creating a firefox profile:

```
    firefox_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(firefox_profile: firefox_profile)
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, marionette: true, desired_capabilities: caps, :http_client=>client
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new driver
```

With the above code, how do I add an additional trusted certificate to firefox?! It might be a self-signed certificate depending on the server under testing.